# Using JQuery Kendo grid in Angular project

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We have a custom grid component which is written in JQuery and in that We are using Kendo Grid. Now We have decided to migrate to Angular 6 but We want to use that custom component still, because It has a lot functionality that will take a lot of time to recreate them in Angular.

So We wrote a wrapper of that component and We are using that in our project. The problem is some functionalities of our custom grid doesn't work. For example Ctrl + C doesn't work or grouping in Kendo grid doesn't work.

Does Anyone encounter these problems like us? We would be happy if you could help us.


The result code would be something like below:

```
<app-custom-grid><div class="k-grid k-widget k-display-block k-grid-lockedcolumns">...</div></app-custom-grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you bind your events to the Jquery Kendo Grid? it seems kendo grid doesn't receive any events from your wrapper grid!

Comment: You made my day :-)